# How to get only name of user from database in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am retrieving user name of the person who is logged in from database. BUt i am getting results like

`[RowDataPacket { First_Name= 'Rani'} ]` But i only need to get that "Rani'. How to do that in node.js?

I only want to get username except those extra parameter(First_Name) e.g "Rani" in above case.

This is part of code where i am getting value.

I have tried var `myJSON = JSON. stringify(obj)` but it shows `[ { First_Name= 'Rani'} ]`.

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var number = request.body.number;
    var password = request.body.pwd;
    var qu = `SELECT 
            First_Name 
        FROM fyp_helpers 
        WHERE Mobile_number = ? 
    UNION 
        SELECT 
            Employer_Fname
        FROM fyp_employers 
        WHERE Employer_Contact = ?`;
    connection.query(qu, [number, number], function (error, results, fields){
        if (error) throw error;
        else
        {
 
     console.log(results);
     ..........
```

Comment: please comprehend the question, it may help others to understand

Comment: @VivekanandanSakthivelu I only want to get username except those extra parameters e.g "Rani" in above case.

Comment: As far, I can understand you need the only name `Rani` from the result of the query. But the, underlying library, return n row, which then is converted to an array of JSON objects.

column name reflects into the JSON attribute and column value is reflected into the JSON  value.

Sometimes, the library allows you to select one row, which return as a JSON object

Comment: @VivekanandanSakthivelu Yes i only need  ```Rani``` . How i can do that?

Comment: that cannot be done, sir!. You can either retrieve one row or n rows. Not the value.

Answer (score 0):

The column names from the query become properties of the objects that represent the rows of results. So use

```
console.log(results[0].First_Name);
```